# Voltage of a free electron

Tags: electrons, potential-energy, voltage, ionization-energy

Every good textbook says that the reduction potentials of half-reactions are all relative.  There is no absolute standard, so the conversion between hydrogen gas and aqueous 1M hydrogen ion at a platinum electron is used.

However ... a voltage can readily be converted into a free energy.  So what happens if you take your half-reaction and ask what the voltage difference would be if your "e-" were a genuine free electron floating in space (well, a 'grounded' region of space...), rather than an electron in that platinum electrode in the hydrogen cell?

Well, it seems to work approximately, sometimes, giving a result around -8 volts.

Copper ionization energy (I) = 745.48 kJ/mol = 7.73 V difference [versus +0.52 V standard reduction potential]

Sodium ionization energy = 496KJ/mol = 5.14 V difference [versus -2.713 V standard]

However...

Hydrogen ionization energy = 1312 kJ/mol = 1312 kJ/(96 485.3415 C) = 13.598 J/C [versus 0 standard].  (Plus another 218 kJ/mol = 2.26 V for diatomic hydrogen formation)

Actually that makes sense because free H+ doesn't exist in water; it makes a covalent bond.  So the H+ isn't nearly as "positive" as it looks from what I assume is a gas phase measurement.  Still, it illustrates that solvation energy, and perhaps other effects I'm not thinking of, complicate the calculation.  (According to https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp063552y and https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/Energies_and_Potentials/Enthalpy/Hydration , the absolute aqueous free energy of solvation of the proton is −265.9 kcal/mol = 1113 kJ/mol; subtracting this from the other two I get 417 kJ/mol = 4.32 V.  The same for sodium, -406 kJ/mol, yields just 0.94 V, so there is something I'm missing.)

Someone must have been down this road before.  Is there a well-considered calculation I can look at?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. But here is at least one item that's missing from your computation: if you wanted to move an electron from a platinum electrode to free space, you would have to supply its [work function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function) of 5-6 eV; the exact value depends on which crystal face is presented at the electrode's surface.

Comment: This is definitely related.  The work function listed for sodium, for example, is 2.36 eV (which is 2.36 V difference, since it's an electron).  But this is the difference for an electron kicked out of a sodium atom in sodium metal, which is different than a sodium atom in water - though now that I think of it, I suppose they would have had to measure that in amalgam, which is something else again.  Nonetheless - the work function gives a potential difference from a "zero volt" vacuum, and that should be experimentally comparable to a reduction potential on a voltmeter.  I think....

Comment: Well, there are some complicated condensed-matter effects that make the ionization energy to remove an electron from a gas-phase sodium atom different from the work function required to remove an electron from the electron ocean in sodium metal. (And I leave the aqueous phase to the chemists.) What I meant was that, if you know these energies relative to a platinum electrode, you could partially submerge your electrode, illuminate the non-submerged part with UV photons above the work function, and generate free electrons that way.